# Analysing periodicity in sparse time series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, signal-processing, fourier-transform

I am interested in looking for periodicities in a several day long recording of electrical activity. The traces present a very steady baseline over which, from time to time, some short events (300-500 ms) appear (hence the *sparse* in the title, although I am not sure it is the right term to use).

Now, the nature of the data prevents me to analyse the trace as a whole (~20 days recorded at 10KHz, my computer will definitely not handle that), so I just wrote a series of routines to find the interesting events, and export their date/time (also their shape, but that is another story) to a text file.

So, I end up with a series of times to analyse.

Just by looking at the raw trace what I can see is:

1. A ~2 hours periodicity in the events
2. The events appear in groups. That is, I have a series of 20-30 events in the course of a couple of minutes, then nothing for ~2 hours, then other 20-30 events and so on. Note that the number of events in a group is variable, can be 30 in one and 5 in the next one.
3. The periodicity is fairly obvious, but it's not perfect: events happen roughly at 2 hours interval, and the exact time may vary from day to day.
4. There may be superimposed periodicities. In particular, I see events at a specific time of the day, which may or may not fit in the abovementioned 2 hours periodicity.

What can I do to statistically determine the periodicity?

What I have tried to do is to make a frequency histogram of the events, binning every 10 minutes, which empirically seemed like a sensible bin size, and then looking at the ACF or the FFT of the counts, but only in a few cases something pops out with the ACF (nothing with FFT).

So, how would you analyse this type of problem?

**Bonus question**: in certain cases I have missing data (1 or 2 days missing for technical reasons). How would I account for that?

PS: I am using R, but any non-R solution will do as well!

**EDIT**

Here is some sample data to play with: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11676289/exampletimes.txt

Here is a plot of the times:

[image: Plot of the times of the events]

and their histogram, in 10 minutes breaks

[image: histogram]

Comment: 1. Do you have your data anywhere so people can look at it? 2. If the data is sparse enough, maybe FT (not FFT) is a good tool ($O(n_{sparse}^2)$ vs. $O(n_{all} \ln n_{all})$ ). 3. Do you care for the shape of the event or do you treat them as points / deltas with their intensity?

Comment: For the moment I don't care for the shape, I would like to make a frequency analysis first, then I will try and concentrate on shapes. I'm not sure I follow you on the FT... could you expand a little bit on that? I'll upload a sample of the data.

Comment: FT - calculating it straightforwardly from its [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). This naive approach may be actually beneficial for very sparse data.

Comment: @Piotr Migdal: ah, OK, I see

Comment: Thx. I see, the date doesn't look much Fourierish.  Have you tried using [recurrence plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot)? (You said you used autocorrelation function, didn't you? I am almost sure you can see sth there, perhaps after the appropriate rescaling.) If you just care to show the burstiness see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20764/6552.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: interesting, I did not know about recurrence plot. I'll try and see if those can lead somewhere...

Comment: Why mess about with FTs and such? If you want to characterize the inter-event intervals, the first step is to extract them from your data set.

Comment: @Cyan: I've done all that standard analysis, but I got nothing really striking from it.

Comment: In other words: is there a standard way to calculate the periodicity of a point process?

Comment: @nico -- a quick literature search shows that work on this kind of estimation is quite recent, e.g., [Shao and Lii, *Modelling non-homogeneous Poisson processes with almost periodic intensity functions*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2010.00758.x/abstract). I don't have access to the paper, but the authors have a [presentation](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2010.00758.x/abstract) which summarizes their results. No available implementation that I can find... This isn't the way I'd go -- I prefer Bayesian methods. If you like, I'll <cont'd>

Comment: ... do some EDA, and if the data looks model-able (is that a real word?) in the following fashion, I'll try to work up some R code for either [log-Gaussian Cox process](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lgcp/index.html) estimation or [scaled logit-Gaussian Cox process](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~lcarin/PoissonProcess.pdf) estimation with the covariance function from [Lii's previous paper on almost periodic processes](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.aos/1152540744) that dealt with continuous state space.

Comment: @Cyan: thank you for the references. Please write this up as an answer, even if it is not complete it gives an interesting starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Fourier Transform may not be the best tool for analysis of such sparse (and spiked) data. [Autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) (perhaps after binning and rescaling) is probably the right tool. Also, one may try using [recurrence plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot).

However, the process does not look periodic at all. It looks more as two Poission processed - one for releasing spikes, and the second - for the spikes themselves. Take a look at [Cox process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox_process) or materials on spike trains (which exhibits similar behavior the the one from your data).

One can analyze how [Fano factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_factor) changes with the window size. For all time windows it is $>1$, contrary to what one could expect for a periodic process (for a periodic process one should get $<1$ for time window related to its periodicity); for Poisson process it should be just $1$.

[image]

Also, you may try to look at the following:

- [One Dimensional Point Processes](https://sites.google.com/site/stefanosresearchguide/Home/teaching/1dimpp09) - lecture notes
- Uri T. Eden, Mark A. Kramer, [Drawing inferences from Fano factor calculations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jneumeth.2010.04.012), Journal of Neuroscience Methods 190 (2010) 149–152, [free pdf](http://math.bu.edu/people/mak/Eden_Kramer_J_Comp_Neuro_2010.pdf)

Comment: Could you give further explanation, perhaps a a reference, on 'binning and rescaling' before autocorrelation?